# Bootstrap. less to css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use twitter bootstrap. In my dev server I connect two less files:
bootstrap.less and style.less:

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
@gridGutterWidth: 30px;

body {...}
```

I redefined some bootstrap variables in my style.less. How to convert bootstrap.less and style.less to css in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a tool such as [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) to create the CSS then reference the CSS in your layouts, or you can use [Less.js](http://lesscss.org/) which converts to CSS on the fly, allowing you to still reference your LESS files in the code.

Comment: I use  Less.js for dev, but I need css for production. The problem is not that use, but how to use it. Join both files for one? bootstrap.less consist of imports only. How to convert it, etc.?

Comment: You can use the SimpLESS tool to convert them to the CSS file that you can then reference on your site. Have a click of the link in my answer and you'll see.

Comment: I get error: Result of expressiin style.less on 'e.massage' [undefined] is not an object. What could it be?

Comment: I have no idea, you'd need to post your LESS in the answer on host it somewhere and link to that.

Comment: @Wolter I suspect 'e.massage' should be 'e.message'

Answer (score 6):

Twitter Bootstrap team has developed its own tool for CSS - [recess](https://github.com/twitter/recess). It compiles LESS, optimizes CSS, lints and converts it according to BS's style guidance. It is available as Node package, install it with `npm`:

```
npm install recess
```

You can run it from command-line with:

```
recess --compile bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css
```

But preferred way is to use Bootstraps `Makefile` by running `make bootstrap` in Bootstrap's folder.